# Pycharm installed but not opening on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, python

I have tested to open the pycharm.sh in terminal but still its not opening
terminal response is something like

> OpenJDK Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in
> version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
>
> WARNING:
> An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>
> WARNING: Illegal
> reflective access by com.intellij.ide.ClassUtilCore to field
> sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.fileCache
>
> WARNING: Please
> consider reporting this to the maintainers of
> com.intellij.ide.ClassUtilCore
>
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to
> enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future
> release
>
> Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment
>
> java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found:
> org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open logisim in Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067569/cant-open-logisim-in-lubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install pycharm-community on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025153/install-pycharm-community-on-ubuntu-16-04)